# Is there a way to put an array into a cookie using only php?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I'm taking the data from my database and trying to put them into the cookie using mysqli_fetch_assoc($result).

At the end the setcookie function doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['remember']) && !isset($_COOKIE['ProfileData']))
{
    session_start();
}
else if(isset($_POST['remember']))
{
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['ProfileData']) && !isset($_COOKIE['ProfileData']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
$birthday = "DATE_FORMAT(Birthday, '%d/%m/%Y')";

if (!isset($username) && !isset($_SESSION['ProfileData']) && !isset($_COOKIE['ProfileData']))
{
    header("location: /login.php");
}
else if(isset($username))
{
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','Signum','3306');   
    $sql = "SELECT Id, Name, Surname, $birthday, Genre, Username FROM MyTable WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if(isset($remember))
    {
        setcookie("ProfileData", mysqli_fetch_assoc($result), time()+(60*60*24*365));
    }
    else
    { 
        $_SESSION['ProfileData'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: First, cookies have a size limitation (4K). Not and ideal place for db results. Second, cookie values can only be strings. You can serialise (or json_encode) a PHP array and store it as string given it's small enough to fit in the cookie space.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may serialize it using [serialize](http://www.php.net/serialize) function. Here is the line code changed:

```
setcookie("ProfileData", serialize(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)), time()+(60*60*24*365));
```

When getting this value from cookie, you need use the [unserialize](http://www.php.net/unserialize) function to convert to an array again.

Comment: Like I said in my comment on the question, it is a very bad idea to attempt to store database results in cookies.

Comment: How do i show to an user his data without saving them?

Comment: @marekful agree it is not a good idea, but user asked in how to put this result in the cookie, just answering it.